# Regular sections of a higher rank bundle on surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective surface and $E$ be a vector bundle of rank $r >2$. Then is it always true that any nonzero global section of it can never be a regular section?

By regular section, I mean the codimension of the  zero scheme of the section in $X$ should be equal to its rank, which in this case is never possible since we are on surface. But I guess, in such situations regularity should be interpreted appropriately.

Any remark/ suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Usually if rank is greater than the dimension, regularity in your sense is interpreted as the zero scheme being empty and then it can happen.

Comment: @Mohan, do you mean empty or a zero dimensional subscheme? Is there a way to make  sure that a higher rank bundle has a regular section e.g. if the dual of the bundle is normalized?

Comment: I meant empty if rank is greater than the dimension.

Comment: @Mohan, thanks! Can we impose some condition on the bundle so that it possesses a regular section?

Comment: In my sense, any globally generated bundle has a regular section.

Comment: @Mohan, I have one final question. Is it true that in order to have the koszul complex resolution corresponding to a section of bundle, the section must be regular ( therefore, it makes sense for any globally generated bundle)?

Comment: @Sherlock Given a nonzero section global section $s: \mathcal{O}_X \to E$, we dualize to get the evaluation map $\pi: E^\vee \to \mathcal{O}_X$, which we can use to construct a Koszul complex. For it to be exact, as you said, you need the section to be regular. That way the image of $\pi$ is locally generated by a regular sequence.